# Open file under cursor in \include instruction

Tags: editors, external-files

I'm looking for a way to easily open files that are included in a document. For example if my document includes another tex document like this

```
\include{content/chapter1}
```

I want to be able to place my cursor somewhere on `chapter1` and press some key and the editor automatically opens `chapter1.tex` in a new tab. It should be an analogy to pressing `F2`-key in QT-Creator to open an included header file. A lot of other IDE's also have this functionality implemented.
Preferably I'm looking for a way to do this with Kile or TeXMaker, but I'm also interested in other editors having this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

texstudio can do this with right click and "open filename":

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I'll see, if anyone will come up with a solution in Kile or TexMaker. If not, I'll except this.

Comment: texstudio is a fork of texmaker, very similar. Worth trying

Comment: I don't like texstudio, because of its implementation of placeholders. You can't use tab to switch to next placeholder while at the same time preserving tabs functionality - if not on a placeholder - of insert a whitespace.